# type error : Cannot read value 'name' of undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Angularjs and firebase to create an app that is a task timer. I create the firebase object and all works fine except when I try to log `task.newTask` to the console. Here's a bit of my code (please note this is not all the code):

```
//HTML
<aside id="sidebar">
    <section id="widget_1">
        <h2 class="titles">Task History:</h2>
        <input id="text-field" type="text" ng-model="taskText" />
        <input id="task-button" type="button" value="Add Task" ng-click="addTask()" />
    </section>

    <section id="widget_2">
        <h2 class="titles">Task List:</h2>            
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="task in timer_tasks | orderBy: '-taskText'">
                <td>{{ task.taskText }}</td>
            </tr>                
        </table>
    </section>
</aside>

//Controller:
(function() {
'use strict'

function HomeCtrl($scope, $firebaseArray, $interval) {
    console.log('I see you home controller ... you are loaded sir!!!')

    var timerRef = firebase.database().ref().child('timer_tasks');        
    $scope.timer_tasks = $firebaseArray(timerRef);


    $scope.addTask = function () {
        $scope.timer_tasks.$add({
            taskText: $scope.taskText,
            newTask: true
        }).then(function (timerRef) {
            $scope.taskText = '';
        });
    };


console.log(task.newTask);
```

On page load the error comes up at `console.log(task.newTask);`

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Atually the correct error message here is "task is not defined" ... Thanks!

Comment: `task` is not defined in the controller, the element you have used in ng-repeat is not tied back to controller automatically. You either use ng-select or ng-click etc.

Comment: I'm using ng-click="addTask()" up on the Add Task button. Is that wrong? Or not sufficient? ... where should I use ng-click if that doesn't work? Thx

Comment: I'm not testing with firebase, but below should help you to move on

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understood correctly, you need to retrieve textbook value in controller which will build `$scope.timer_tasks` and later can be retrieved back to view in `ng-repeat`.

view

```
<aside id="sidebar">
   <section id="widget_1">
     <h4 class="titles">Task History:</h4>
       <input id="text-field" type="text" ng-model="taskText" />
       <input id="task-button" 
        type="button" 
        value="Add Task" 
        ng-click="addTask(taskText)"/>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Script

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.addTask = function (value) {
      console.log(" clicked : "+value);
    };
});
```

All i did was bind the value upon addTask click from ng-model to ng-click and as you can see now you have that value in addTask function.